# Issue with django channels `ValueError: Invalid IPv6 URL`

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-channels

I’ve setup django channels in my project and other things like APIs and Other admin urls are working fine, but when I try to create a socket connection in my project I’m getting this error

```
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/notification/ [127.0.0.1:48494]
Exception inside application: Invalid IPv6 URL
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jlp-020/Projects/POC_flutter_dating_application_BE/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 101, in __call__
    return await self.application(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/jlp-020/Projects/POC_flutter_dating_application_BE/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/channels/routing.py", line 62, in __call__
    return await application(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/jlp-020/Projects/POC_flutter_dating_application_BE/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/channels/security/websocket.py", line 35, in __call__
    if self.valid_origin(parsed_origin):
  File "/home/jlp-020/Projects/POC_flutter_dating_application_BE/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/channels/security/websocket.py", line 54, in valid_origin
    return self.validate_origin(parsed_origin)
  File "/home/jlp-020/Projects/POC_flutter_dating_application_BE/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/channels/security/websocket.py", line 73, in validate_origin
    return any(
  File "/home/jlp-020/Projects/POC_flutter_dating_application_BE/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/channels/security/websocket.py", line 74, in <genexpr>
    pattern == "*" or self.match_allowed_origin(parsed_origin, pattern)
  File "/home/jlp-020/Projects/POC_flutter_dating_application_BE/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/channels/security/websocket.py", line 102, in match_allowed_origin
    pattern_hostname = urlparse("//" + pattern).hostname or pattern
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/parse.py", line 400, in urlparse
    splitresult = urlsplit(url, scheme, allow_fragments)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/parse.py", line 495, in urlsplit
    raise ValueError("Invalid IPv6 URL")
ValueError: Invalid IPv6 URL
WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/notification/ [127.0.0.1:48494]
```

Can anyone help me with this one.

Comment: if possible share your settings.py as well
or atleast CHANNEL_LAYERS and ALLOWED_HOSTS
and the IPv6 URL that's being used, if you're using that explicitely!

Comment: @HarshitJain It's been solved but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue, it's because my ALLOWED_HOSTS are not properly configured.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).